# Add code to WooCommerce Cart Page with hook beside update cart button

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On a standard WooCommerce Cart page like [storefront theme](https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/cart/) under the product row is a row of coupon code to the left and a update cart on the right.  I can use `woocommerce_cart_coupon` to hook beside the coupon on the left:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon', 'addcode' );
function addcode() {echo 'hello';}
```

This code goes into a left sided div so I cant move it to the right side.

What is the hook to get on the right beside the update cart?

`woocommerce_cart_contents` & `woocommerce_after_cart_contents` are too high, and `woocommerce_after_cart_table` is too low on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`woocommerce_cart_actions`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-cart-cart.html#source-view.150) hook.

This code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions', 'addcode' );
function addcode() {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

It will show the text *"hello"* after the *"Update cart"* button:

[image]

You can change the position of the element by adding a CSS rule. For example, **to show the *"Update cart"* button on the right** you can use:

```
body.woocommerce-cart button[name=update_cart] {
    float:right;
}
```

Or you can always change the cart template: `/woocommerce/cart/cart.php`. See [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) for more information.

Comment: That's the one.  I was using businessbloomer but they didnt have it!  I had the code on the cart.php but was trying to remove theme overrides.  If you wanted to do a CSS add on I would think giving the code a specific id and moving it would be easier than moving the update cart button?

Comment: Sure. You can choose to add an id or class attribute to the element you add in order to apply CSS rules.